# Mac OS; Python3; FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: ''. How to fix it?

Tags: python, terminal, python-3.6

I'm quit new at Python, and tried to launch the script

> convert_to_tfrecord.py

(Neural Networks; It should train dataset of Images with some libraries ...)

Instruction:

> Now you’re ready to run the TFRecord script. Run the command below
>   from the tensorflow/models/research directory, and pass it the
>   following flags (run it twice: once for training data, once for test
>   data):

```
python convert_labels_to_tfrecords.py \
--output_path=train.record \ 
--images_dir=path/to/your/training/images/ \
--labels_dir=path/to/training/label/xml/
```

So to suit my OS X, I ran this script by python3... changes name of script... and set a directory ... 
I'm at directory where my script is; Where my folder is; Where my libraries are.
So in my case:

```
python3 convert_to_tfrecord.py \
--output_path=train.record \ 
--images_dir=ENFj/ \
--labels_dir=ENFj/xml/
```

Result:

```
Oleksandrs-MacBook-Air:research jaskier$ python3 convert_to_tfrecord.py \
> --output_path=train.record \ 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "convert_to_tfrecord.py", line 89, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 126, in run
    _sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "convert_to_tfrecord.py", line 81, in main
    for filename in os.listdir(FLAGS.images_dir):
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: ''
Oleksandrs-MacBook-Air:research jaskier$ --images_dir=ENFj/ \
> --labels_dir=ENFj/xml/
```

Code of "convert_to_tfrecord":

```
import os
import io
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import tensorflow as tf

from object_detection.utils import dataset_util
from PIL import Image


flags = tf.app.flags
flags.DEFINE_string('output_path', '', 'Path to output TFRecord')
flags.DEFINE_string('images_dir', '', 'Path to directory of images')
flags.DEFINE_string('labels_dir', '', 'Path to directory of labels')
FLAGS = flags.FLAGS


def create_tf_example(example):

    image_path = os.getcwd() + '/' +  FLAGS.images_dir + example
    labels_path = os.getcwd() + '/' +  FLAGS.labels_dir + os.path.splitext(example)[0] + '.xml'

    # Read the image
    img = Image.open(image_path)
    width, height = img.size
    img_bytes = io.BytesIO()
    img.save(img_bytes, format=img.format)

    height = height
    width = width
    encoded_image_data = img_bytes.getvalue()
    image_format = img.format.encode('utf-8')

    # Read the label XML
    tree = ET.parse(labels_path)
    root = tree.getroot()
    xmins = xmaxs = ymins = ymaxs = list()

    for coordinate in root.find('object').iter('bndbox'):
        xmins = [int(coordinate.find('xmin').text)]
        xmaxs = [int(coordinate.find('xmax').text)]
        ymins = [int(coordinate.find('ymin').text)]
        ymaxs = [int(coordinate.find('ymax').text)]

    classes_text = ['tswift'.encode('utf-8')]
    classes = [1]

    tf_example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature={
        'image/height': dataset_util.int64_feature(height),
        'image/width': dataset_util.int64_feature(width),
        'image/filename': dataset_util.bytes_feature(encoded_image_data),
        'image/source_id': dataset_util.bytes_feature(encoded_image_data),
        'image/encoded': dataset_util.bytes_feature(encoded_image_data),
        'image/format': dataset_util.bytes_feature(image_format),
        'image/object/bbox/xmin': dataset_util.float_list_feature(xmins),
        'image/object/bbox/xmax': dataset_util.float_list_feature(xmaxs),
        'image/object/bbox/ymin': dataset_util.float_list_feature(ymins),
        'image/object/bbox/ymax': dataset_util.float_list_feature(ymaxs),
        'image/object/class/text': dataset_util.bytes_list_feature(classes_text),
        'image/object/class/label': dataset_util.int64_list_feature(classes),
    }))
    return tf_example


def main(_):
    writer = tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter(FLAGS.output_path)

    for filename in os.listdir(FLAGS.images_dir):
        tf_example = create_tf_example(filename)
        writer.write(tf_example.SerializeToString())

    writer.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    tf.app.run()
```

Tried different stuff:
1. UPDATED request to (one line + deleted "\" because as someone mentioned below, it was an error of page's PHP interpreter... it used \n and forgot to hide the output text):

```
python3 convert_to_tfrecord.py 
--output_path=train.record 
--images_dir=ENFj
--labels_dir=ENFj/xml
```

2."find . -name ".DS_Store" -delete"
3. Tried again:

> File
>   "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/Image.py",
>   line 2543, in open fp = builtins.open(filename, "rb")
>   IsADirectoryError: [Errno 21] Is a directory:
>   '/Users/jaskier/Downloads/models/research/ENFj/xml'

Comment: I think your running script could be copied from blog with invisible character `\n`. Just try `python3 convert_to_tfrecord.py --output_path=train.record --images_dir=ENFj/ --labels_dir=ENFj/xml/`

Comment: @Oleksandr thanks for following up! I'm glad we got this going!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is set up to interpret all files in `--images_dir` to some image processing machinery. This means that any non-image resources in the `--images_dir` will cause the script to break.

One solution is to ensure `--images_dir` contains only image files (i.e. ensure that directory doesn't contain XML files or files that begin with a ., like `.git` or `.DS_Store`.

Another solution would be to modify the source code itself to only work on image files. Something like this could be used:

```
import glob

# only match jpg files in the images_dir
for filename in glob.glob(FLAGS.images_dir + '/*.jpg'):
  tf_example = create_tf_example(filename)
  # copy the other lines here as needed
```

Comment: almost ... however after this code I have direct error to line 33 - this 2 lines.

Comment: File "convert_to_tfrecord.py", line 33
    image_path = FLAGS.images_dir + example
             ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block

Comment: @Oleksandr Python is a whitespace-sensitive language. Try inserting 4 spaces before each of these lines...

Comment: Tried different stuff, but I have only:

  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 2543, in open
    fp = builtins.open(filename, "rb")
IsADirectoryError: [Errno 21] Is a directory: '/Users/jaskier/Downloads/models/research/ENFj/xml'

Something wrong with path I guess.. maybe even module responsible for path(

Comment: @Oleksandr please update your question with the following info: add `print(image_path)` after the `image_path` line I wrote above, then paste the full updated source code you're running, then paste the full command you run on the command line, then paste the full output error

Comment: Aha, move `xml/` out of `ENFj/`. `ENFj/` should contain only images, and `xml/` should contain only xml; then you can run: `python3 convert_to_tfrecord.py
--output_path=train.record
--images_dir=ENFj/
--labels_dir=xml/`

Comment: please post it as an answer below. It works. I want to mark your answer as correct)) Also needed to delete "find . -name ".DS_Store" -delete" several times had an error of unrecognised file

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was just a simple dumb mistake: when I changed manually the name of my folder:

I have left a *SPACE* after the name - and when I was calling it with **os** or **glob.glob** I was getting: `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:`

After spending some time searching for the problem(even changing some files names and removing some subfolders) I went back to the folder, deleted that extra space, and everything worked just fine.